# Jquery $.POST url not recieving values in response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .post

I have task to submit 2 values to a php file using ajax for which I have done the below code in jquery `$.POST`

```
$.post(
    "http://localhost/gcm_server_files/sample.php",
     {regId: id,message:msg},
     function(data){
      alert(data);      
    });
```

and the code in `sample.php` is:

```
echo $_POST['regId'].' AND '.$_POST['message'];
```

I can see the POST values in console, but cannot see the response..

The values I am posting are:

```
regID:APA91bGmks8s9ytasjkhdjkhsdjkahsdkjhakjlYkpWpPmjB_nUhbTmVtAho7M6o-W4rsVJorB-ozX9v50YkBMg
message: Testing
```

Can someone show me whats wrong with code?

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: I am looking into the Fire bug where I can see the the URL in red color but with status 200OK

Comment: And what's the response?

Comment: I had 0 errors in replication testing.

Comment: Can you open sample.php in your browser? Try echoing something at the top of the page, just to test it.

Comment: Nothing in response blank in HTML

Comment: @Shomz Yes I did that and I can get the echo'ed value..

Comment: @OMTheEternity What is the address of the page making this request? Is it also at `http://localhost/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the url; 
    You are using the absolute path ( `http://localhost/gcm_server_files/sample.php`) in URL.
     Try to use the relative path of file in the URL (/sample.php) .

See this for more detail on the same origin policy that applies to Ajax request.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

```
  Try this 

    $.post(
    "relative_path_to/sample.php",
     {regId: id,message:msg},
     function(data){
      alert(data);      
    });
```

Comment: sorry to say but would not affect the things.. if domain is same it should work.. its not the crossed domain example..

Comment: i can bet absolute url will work.. if you both pages are on same domain.

Comment: @DeepakSharma But the elative path concept worked for me, yes both files are on same server and on same root path.